# BBC iPlayer downloader app DRM issue

Tags: windows-8, download, license

Got a strange issue with the iPlayer app on one of my computers. For absolutely any download it gives a error:

> DRM License Failed

I've tried:

- Un-installing then re-installing
- Running it as an administrator
- Setting the firewall to allow it both incoming and outgoing connections

After clearing the logs files and trying to download for example a London Marathon video, in the logs there is:

```
info: Downloader window opened
info: Added file watcher for "C:\Users\the_user\Videos\BBC iPlayer Downloads"
info: Programme error London Marathon 2019: 2. Live Coverage Part 1, reason DRM Licence failed, detail Failed to execute 'createMediaKeys' on 'MediaKeySystemAccess': Unable to create CDM.
info: License failed NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'createMediaKeys' on 'MediaKeySystemAccess': Unable to create CDM.
info: Downloader window opened
info: Added file watcher for "C:\Users\the_user\Videos\BBC iPlayer Downloads"
info: Programme error London Marathon 2019: 2. Live Coverage Part 1, reason DRM Licence failed, detail Failed to execute 'createMediaKeys' on 'MediaKeySystemAccess': Unable to create CDM.
info: License failed NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'createMediaKeys' on 'MediaKeySystemAccess': Unable to create CDM.
info: Restarting programme download (with existing resolver)
warn: Refusing download of "London Marathon" as it is already in progress
info: Restarting programme download (with existing resolver)
info: Programme error London Marathon 2019: 2. Live Coverage Part 1, reason DRM Licence failed, detail Failed to execute 'createMediaKeys' on 'MediaKeySystemAccess': Unable to create CDM.
info: License failed NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'createMediaKeys' on 'MediaKeySystemAccess': Unable to create CDM.
```

Both computers are running Windows 8.1

On the PC where the problem is, I had a clear out of Windows components that I thought I wasn't using (removed via Programs and Issues), I've no idea if it's one of them things that the iPlayer app might be looking for.

There's no Windows updates pending (either to download or to install)
(From IP Chicken)

```
Name Address: cpc83987-pool15-2-0-cust968.15-1.cable.virginm.net
    Remote Port: 24306
    Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
```

Both computers within the UK, same ISP but different locations (approx 1/4 mile apart)

Comment: 1) Are you in the UK? 2) Are you using a VPN with a terminus outside of the UK? 3) What does http://ipchicken.com show your external IP address to be? Please click [edit] and add your answers to the original post, for the BBC restricts much of its content to only users within the UK and uses the nominal locations of IP addresses to determine if you are an authorised viewer of content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I've managed to get it going, if anyone else gets a similar problem, try deleting everything in the folder:

C:\Users\the_user\AppData\Roaming\BBCiPlayerDownloads

Be warned - I've no idea if that'll cause all saved programs to be deleted - I didn't have any programs saved when trying it

I'm guessing that something within that folder must have gotten corrupted at some point, no idea as to exactly what was corrupted or how it got corrupted.